# Multiply a string by an integer?

Tags: xpath, xquery

In python, for example, I can do this

```
"X" * 3
```

or, more importantly (in this case)

```
"XO" * 3
```

and get `XXX` and `XOXOXO`, respectively.

I'm trying to replicate this with xpath/xquery. Ideally, it should be something like

```
"XO" * count(something)
```

The closest I could get is by sort of faking the output by creating a string with a length close to my estimate of what `count(something)` is going to be and then slice it with `substring()`. So if my `count(something)` returns `2`

```
substring("XXX",1,count(//something))
```

would return `XX`. 
It gets slightly more complicated if my string is `XO`, in which case I have to modify it to

```
substring("XOXOXO",1,count(//something) * 2)
```

to get `XOXO`.

However, in addition to feeling hacky, these require an estimate of `count()` and the creation of a string of the correct length (+ some safety margin).

Is there a better way to do it in xpath or xquery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `((1 to 3) ! 'XO') => string-join()` and of course you can put that into a function if you like with a parameter for the string and the number of "multiplications" you want:

```
declare function local:multiply-string($input as xs:string, $factor as xs:integer) as xs:string
{
   ((1 to $factor) ! $input) => string-join() 
};

local:multiply-string('XO', 3)
```

https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPqteBa/1

Comment: Still playing with your fiddle; it returns the right output but, interestingly, it also raises a `lexical analysis failed` warning.

Comment: @Jack, yes, sorry about that, the fiddle uses the ACE editor component whose XQuery mode unfortunately has never been updated to parse XQuery 3.1 features like maps or `=>`. Unfortunately correcting such a mode is a bit too difficult to me. So you will have to live with some XQuery 3.1 syntax being reported there as errors.

Comment: Thanks, Martin. FYI, I also tried both options with BaseX - no errors!